# How do I write Playbooks to check Cpu Usage and Memory in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, memory, ansible, cpu

it was easier to find playbook for unix/linux ,but here im trying to write playbook for a Windows Sever

Comment: I"m not sure what your goal is, but perhaps you don't want to be doing this with Ansible, but rather a monitoring system. Take a look at Zabbix or the ELK stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try as below

```
- name: CPU usage
  win_command: wmic cpu get loadpercentage
  register: cpu_results

- name: Memory
  win_command: wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value
  register: mem_results
```

or

```
- name: Memory
  win_command: systeminfo
  register: memory_results
```

Comment: Yes , Got it Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

When using Ansible to manage Windows, many of the syntax and rules that apply for Unix/Linux hosts also apply to Windows, but there are still some differences when it comes to components like path separators and OS-specific tasks. This document covers details specific to using Ansible for Windows.

Use the `win_command` or `win_shell` module to run commands via a shell (defaults to PowerShell) on the target host.

You can simply run whatever command you want to run and can check any details about the target hosts.

Below is the link for further reading :

[Using Ansible and Windows](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_usage.html)

Comment: I am unable to find for cpu usage and memory for a playbook. I don't have any idea of how to write a playbook for CPU usage in windows.It would be great if you could help me with this